# PHP Regex returning array with values empty

Tags: php, regex

So I'm reading a bunch of PHP files trying to find each accurance of a function call,

the function I'm looking for is `".lng("something")." OR '.lng('something').'`

I'm using the following function to search

```
function fetchAllBetween($needle1,$needle2,$haystack,$include=false){

        $matches = array();

        $exp = "|{$needle1}(.*){$needle2}|U";
        //exit($exp);
        preg_match_all($exp,$haystack,$matches);

        $i = ($include == true) ? 0 : 1 ;

        return $matches[$i];

    }
```

So I run it like this

```
$tmp2 = fetchAllBetween("lng('","')", $theData);
    print_r($tmp2);
```

This returns empty arrays, however If I try running the following

```
$tmp2 = fetchAllBetween("lng",".", $theData);
```

It returns an array with the values empty tho... Anyone could give me a hand with this? Basically I'm trying to retrieve the argument that is passed into lng() function in a bunch of files..

Comment: You relly shouldn't use `|` as the regex delimiter. It has a special meaning in regexes (separating alternatives) and by using it as the delimiter you cannot use it for this purpose anymore!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will do

```
preg_match_all('#\.lng\(([\'"])(.*?)(?:\1)\)#', $str, $matches);
```

http://ideone.com/IQCzX

Comment: Thanks, had to remove the . then it worked as I needed it(as sometimes it was passed into functions/objects) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your resulting expression is `lng(('".*"'))`, there are several things you'll want to change. Try using this:

```
$tmp2 = fetchAllBetween("\.lng\(['\"]","[\"']\)\.", $theData);
    print_r($tmp2);
```

Things to note:

- I've added the `.` (and escaped it)
- I've escaped the brackets
- I've put the single *and* double quotes in a character class so it will match either (and escaped the double for the PHP string)

Comment: same as before, returned empty arrays, any other ideas?

Comment: It would be much better to use `preg_quote()` inside the function instead of escaping the arguments manually.