# RegEx returns an empty array

Tags: php, regex

So, I'm trying to catch 3 letter word from a text file. I've created a RegEx, but it return an EMPTY array. And I'm not able to figure out why!
Here's a part of the text file.

```
================================================
Header of File with time and date
================================================
Loaded options from XML file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml
extendedPrintPDF started
Postfix '3.0' was append from file 'ESQ030112ELAM_lo-metadata.xml' for file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
printPDF started
PDF Export Preset: Some preset
PDF file created: ''/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.pdf'.
File someFileName.xml removed
postprocessingDocument started
INDD file removed: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
```

Here's the RegEx I have:

```
/^Loaded options from XML file: '\/.*\/SM_Folder\/([a-zA-Z]{3})\/[a-zA-Z]+_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml$/im
```

If I remove `\` in front of  `\/([a-zA-Z]{3})`, I get an `Unknown modifier:(` error.

Can someone please tell me what I need to do to grab the "ESQ" from the first line of the record? The 3 letter word would be different in other records and so, I can't really design my RegEx to catch only ESQ. It might be ABC or XYZ for example. But, it would remain as a 3 letter word.
Any useful inputs would be appreciated.

Also, this post didnt help much either: [PHP Regex returning array with values empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379990/php-regex-returning-array-with-values-empty)

Note:

```
options.xml
```

doesn't end with `'` because it is not supposed to!

Comment: Which concrete function are you using to return the array? Normally an empty array is a sign that there were no matches. But furthermost there are normally return values that tell you whether - or not - and often the exact count of matches. What do these (foremost more important) return values say? How many matches are reported? E.g. if there are no matches, gettting an empty array is perfectly valid.

Comment: Do you get any `E_WARNING`s or `E_NOTICE`s? (turn on strict mode if you haven't already)

Comment: You have multiline option enabled `m` at the end of your regex, and you have start `^` and end `$` flags. With this configuration it will try to match the beginning and end of the entire string instead of the beginning and end of the line.

Comment: @SalmanA: `\1` is the backreference to the first (`1`) matching group.

Comment: @SalmanA: Yes, that works in the pattern, too, not only for replacing. See http://php.net/regexp.reference.back-references

Comment: @hakre: I'm testing it here for now:
http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php And it is pretty reliable most of the time.

Comment: @hakre: Not really using a function because the tool does it for me. But, its `preg_match_all('{{your regular expression}}', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);` if it makes your job for now (of helping me) easier.

Comment: I could now test with your code and if you still have the problem, see  my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14164208/367456 what I've found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression pattern and the file-data you have provided in your question are not resulting in an empty array. At least not for me (read on later). With `preg_match_all` I'll get one match properly. I've using this code:

```
$file = <<<FILE
================================================
Header of File with time and date
================================================
Loaded options from XML file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml
extendedPrintPDF started
Postfix '3.0' was append from file 'ESQ030112ELAM_lo-metadata.xml' for file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
printPDF started
PDF Export Preset: Some preset
PDF file created: ''/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.pdf'.
File someFileName.xml removed
postprocessingDocument started
INDD file removed: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/someFile.indd
FILE;

$pattern = '/^Loaded options from XML file: \'\/.*\/SM_Folder\/([a-zA-Z]{3})\/[a-zA-Z]+_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml$/im';

$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $file, $matches);

var_dump($result, $matches);
```

Result:

```
int(1)
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(127) "Loaded options from XML file: '/Thisis/some/Users/sumuser/Desktop/SM_Folder/ESQ/Virtual_Proof_ESQ/processing/ID2PDF_options.xml"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "ESQ"
  }
}
```

You probably get a result similar as the following (which is also by the exact same code as above but on a different computer as [demo here](http://eval.in/5972)):

```
int(0)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

If you get this result, than this is a sign that the `^` and `$` in multiline mode do not match the end of lines because you don't have `\n` there but most likely the CRLF sequence (DOS/Windows line-ending). You can take all these sequences by using the `ANYCRLF` option:

```
$pattern = '/(*ANYCRLF)^Loaded options from XML file: \'\/.*\/SM_Folder\/([a-zA-Z]{3})\/[a-zA-Z]+_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml$/im';
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

This then should give you the results. See [the working demo](http://eval.in/5973).

Comment: Not to point to the obvious, but you're looking for `SM_Folder` in the pattern which is not part of that string - nowhere. - Check this instead: http://eval.in/5984

Comment: **Kicked myself a thousand times, in my mind** 
Thank you soo much, hakre! Thanks a ton for this help. I was stuck with this since yesterday evening!Thanks so much. Also, it would be great if you could tell me how to like comments here! 
**Still thanking** :)

Comment: You can press the up-arrow next to the comment (on the left, it appears if you move the mouse there). You can also upvote the answer ;) - And next time you ask about a problem, show the code, because it often tells the story.

Comment: Yeah. I'm still learning new things. And people like you are helping me a great deal. 
Thanks... :)

Comment: @haker: Deleted my 1st comment because I'm hesitant to share the contents of the log file. :) Hope that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z]_Proof
```

Should be

```
[a-zA-Z]+_Proof
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! But, doesn't make much difference. Still get the empty array!

Answer (score 0):

`\/([a-zA-Z]{3})` is not a valid regular expression. You're missing delimiters.

```
preg_match_all(":\/([a-zA-Z]{3}):", $input, $matches);
```

You can pick any character, here I chose `:`.

Comment: But, that only cuts down each part of the part to 3 letter words. I'm looking for something that would just populate the array with the letter COS, ABC, XYZ, etc. 
And it should grab it only from the first line of the record, which starts with Loaded options...

Comment: You didn't post your full regular expression, so I don't know what it is. Add the delimiters and you should be fine.

Comment: This is the RegEx I'm using: 
`/^Loaded options from XML file: '\/.*\/SM_Folder\/([a-zA-Z]{3})\/[a-zA-Z]+_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml'$/im`.
I stick this in, with the data, on [link](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php) and I get an empty array.

Comment: In your source data the line that has `options.xml` doesn't end in a `'`, is that it?

Comment: I dont think so. Because, even `/^Loaded options from XML file: '\/.*\/SM_Folder:\/([a-zA-Z]{3}):\/[a-zA-Z]+_Proof_\1\/processing\/ID2PDF_options.xml/im` returns an EMPTY array. I am just not able to resolve this since yesterday evening and this is frustrating me to no end!! :(

Comment: The `'` is missing after options.xml because it is supposed to appear only later. But, even after taking the `'` off from the regEx, it returns an empty array.

Comment: Reduce it till you have something that matches and build it back up from there. I'd remove the `\1` by just a generic match since it's not really important what is there (unless it is of course).

Comment: Have tried it all and run into different errors and this is the best I've come up with until now. I thought its something trivial, but doesn't look like.